# Finding latest date in Django Q object

Tags: python, django, date

Not 100% happy with the structure of this code, but unfortunately I can't change it at the moment. I'm searching a big database in Django, and because of technical limitations, I must store a list of `Q` objects, and use Django's `reduce()` function to merge the `Q` objects into a single `Queryset`. I currently have a model like such:

```
class Obj(models.Model):
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    modified = models.DateField('%Y-%m-%d', default='1900-01-01')
```

I am currently using the following code to select rows that have an `id_number` present in a list, `latest_ids`:

```
split_queries = []
for id_num in latest_ids:
    split_queries.append(Q(id_number=id_num))
result = Obj.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, split_queries))
```

This is working as I expected, but I would like to only keep the row where `id_number=id_num` and the date `modified` is the latest. I have seen solutions such as using Django's `aggregate()` function or the `latest()` function, but I can't figure out how to use these with `Q` objects. I was hoping for a `Q` object such as

```
Q(id_number=id_num, Max('modified'))
```

is behavior like this possible with `Q` objects in Django?

**EDIT**
The system I am working on uses SQLite. The database is large, and issues were run into in the past with `Too Many SQL variables` (SQLite only allows 1000), and for queries where many `id_number`s are selected, breaking the query into smaller groups of `Q` objects solved these issues.

The database has many different `id_number`s, but many rows have the same `id_number`s. I would like to be able to, for each in `latest_id`s, select the single row that matches that `id_number` and that has the latest `modified` date (or multiple rows if the dates are the same).

Comment: But here there are multiple `id_number`s?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple `id_number`s. Many rows have the same `id_number`, and for each group of those I would like to only select the row with the latest date in `modified`. However, each `id_number` in the the `latest_ids` list will be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your `Q` in the first place. `Obj.objects.filter(id_number__in=latest_ids)` gives you the rows where `id_number` is one of the `latest_ids`.

EDIT: Seems you need to keep the Q() queries for your use case. In which case it's not possible to add what you want inside the Q() filter.

But grouping and annotating the resulting query might not be such an issue. Try this:

```
Obj.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, split_queries))\
    .values('id_number').annotate(latest_modified=Max('modified'))
```

Comment: Edited the question for why `Q` objects were chosen over a standard `filter()`

Comment: But that doesn’t change the fact that you can order by modified date to fetch the last one. Or aggregate at the end to fetch the max value. You can’t do that in a Q filter since that filters each row (row by row), whereas the latest date is an aggregate.

Comment: If I call `order_by('modified')` after `filter(reduce...)` has been called, the `QuerySet` will contain many `id_number`s, and I believe `last()` will ignore each `id_number` and focus only on the `modified` date. I would like to keep 1 row for each `id_number`, which is the row that has the latest `modified` date

Comment: I don’t understand. You should clarify that in your question. What do you mean 1 row for each id_number? You mean there are multiple rows with the same id_number?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to hopefully increase clarity of what the database contains and what I am hoping to achieve

Comment: When trying the updated approach, the `latest_modified` values do not seem to contain the `Max` value for that `id_number`, each `latest_modified` is equal to its `modified` date

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying. This groups all the same id_numbers together so there’s just one entry per id_number (and no two equal ones) and annotates each entry with the max modified value within that group. Isn’t that what you want? What do you mean by “does not contain the Max value for that id_number”?